# requests response 404 within loop

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, http-status-code-404, response

I have to make several requests of type post. The problem is that these requests succeed when done one by one, but fail from the first one when looped. Below is a minimal example to represent the problem:

In this example, the following data will be used, in addition to a function in charge of preparing the form:

```
url    = 'https://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/resultadosArchivos'
geom   = [[-0.7987325116517696, 37.656087192208055], [-0.7985235003240462, 37.65594375741643], [-0.7985474794897984, 37.65594420513967], [-0.7962286729592958, 37.65491394491624], [-0.7949711771874296, 37.65439325635649], [-0.7948052726279082, 37.65432623336894], [-0.7946455258919144, 37.65425006531448], [-0.7939447445238755, 37.65390034431402], [-0.7930765882652716, 37.653645662371325], [-0.7928371577553093, 37.653629258857535], [-0.7927458275725201, 37.653675236293466], [-0.7927053807125997, 37.65372455058274], [-0.7927884208289694, 37.65385724465684], [-0.7926681433825032, 37.653954513655194], [-0.792575645530591, 37.65395340428432], [-0.7924595271013085, 37.65392500239512], [-0.7923654133599405, 37.65386243924444], [-0.7923586801955145, 37.65378601380589], [-0.792389467412715, 37.65365783505304], [-0.792482171707259, 37.653666723797905], [-0.7925276251447322, 37.65365088429604], [-0.7925069640803623, 37.65353843277117], [-0.7924738198758707, 37.653442438016874], [-0.7922656547240149, 37.65325136858154], [-0.7916336838941993, 37.65296104109313], [-0.7906608046426835, 37.65253706195932], [-0.789859544739282, 37.652191573953104], [-0.7890979151416527, 37.65190547880289], [-0.7884184369493955, 37.65170103400106], [-0.7881677205784622, 37.651663999323716], [-0.7879491369639361, 37.65165274572728], [-0.7878519534787827, 37.65169384085334], [-0.7877669461771315, 37.65184935599399], [-0.7877052851683851, 37.651886606109], [-0.7876663921599033, 37.651883492014456], [-0.7876193563070684, 37.65185161287172], [-0.7875758128344686, 37.651803108762095], [-0.787595705852743, 37.65173910446636], [-0.7874860443828382, 37.65166213270359], [-0.7875418448749817, 37.65153303937935], [-0.7875054721557575, 37.65134399289938], [-0.7874169809039685, 37.65121349779351], [-0.7867997196934734, 37.65095417892957], [-0.7861513320289116, 37.65072873134976], [-0.7857355485885904, 37.650657455511464], [-0.785280905779632, 37.65069851139792], [-0.7849255507941967, 37.65078911785241], [-0.7847029828011444, 37.650714264246425], [-0.7842524443346003, 37.65053650964672], [-0.7838280321654223, 37.6503878566359], [-0.7835275308116117, 37.650711248942464], [-0.7836345072661536, 37.65074425640996], [-0.7835138337346836, 37.651071028725625], [-0.7835928299599798, 37.65113736806658], [-0.7835527655151646, 37.651193839416145], [-0.7838616376923603, 37.65129501921869], [-0.7843139222245648, 37.65141415307192], [-0.7847964158938069, 37.65156627995554], [-0.78474285152791, 37.65176420813136], [-0.7845662012659709, 37.65210781247205], [-0.7842281897219018, 37.6527345065747], [-0.7843805506559717, 37.65290546652781], [-0.784349325103479, 37.65304794090465], [-0.7842535302850214, 37.6530926356268], [-0.7840163115121471, 37.65305241226402], [-0.7817974804261126, 37.65236977674855], [-0.7819689485356517, 37.652012966289625], [-0.7821427705277021, 37.65203829027675], [-0.7823866982011976, 37.65153234082982], [-0.7825407500607616, 37.651217821209926], [-0.7827390607256998, 37.650851975925946], [-0.7829338730447392, 37.65053478475626], [-0.783393004380502, 37.65066549571425], [-0.7836816266544042, 37.650318036939794], [-0.783567322015534, 37.65025685960739], [-0.7833904639916066, 37.6502003084091], [-0.7825245296654971, 37.649743075111], [-0.7823227110937427, 37.6496365085595], [-0.7822329418668421, 37.64965372666812], [-0.7821576938223961, 37.6496051045372], [-0.7821421199218732, 37.649532218570585], [-0.7816858951552544, 37.649300245531634], [-0.7805521543362414, 37.64908399347945], [-0.7803282864809604, 37.649054589822235], [-0.7801456836515582, 37.64907767068538], [-0.7800761543991722, 37.64906616639383], [-0.7800045564118352, 37.649028391395845], [-0.7799592289193188, 37.64897909102425], [-0.7797597221572838, 37.64886076739338], [-0.7795058489242883, 37.64878662170458], [-0.7792283469919488, 37.64873111275999], [-0.7790372272386331, 37.64872635722775], [-0.7789194352174392, 37.648699858334176], [-0.778804773976399, 37.648669086624665], [-0.7778141437583858, 37.648523948358914], [-0.7777150782799568, 37.64853882093335], [-0.7776130215515802, 37.648574154531424], [-0.7775018779793822, 37.64857573290953], [-0.7773195479638699, 37.64857350352225], [-0.7772896660195561, 37.64858758499213], [-0.7772638002360703, 37.648600211337396], [-0.7772343124685813, 37.64860859678497], [-0.7771868372772924, 37.648604066894805], [-0.7770275624203644, 37.64855070022684], [-0.7767453808107654, 37.64847750615848], [-0.7760668319944926, 37.648379308639875], [-0.7752440398443159, 37.648375748777454], [-0.7751086923006878, 37.6484400595881], [-0.7749703988917745, 37.648496284574826], [-0.7748675666941274, 37.64853474973117], [-0.7746844608913589, 37.64863773016901], [-0.7744097905383693, 37.64884435384916], [-0.7742934381441815, 37.64890968743158], [-0.7742141018066486, 37.64907604806267], [-0.7741475571806808, 37.64929605953145], [-0.7740239822894538, 37.649428120561055], [-0.7737454703615131, 37.649386013452485], [-0.7734229161094693, 37.64922038498878], [-0.7738886129527545, 37.647792961075645], [-0.7741297633914515, 37.64719944232666], [-0.77475623106324, 37.646855597688194], [-0.7807331867395281, 37.64754048595543], [-0.7866276843572312, 37.648986517911474], [-0.7948080429780471, 37.65223945424147], [-0.8001955125224235, 37.654629073806476], [-0.7987325116517696, 37.656087192208055]]
series = ['MDT05', 'MDS05', '02107', 'LIDAR', 'LIDA2']

def payload(series,geom):
    data = {'geom': 'Polygon',
            'coords': '{"type" : "FeatureCollection", "features" : [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [%s]}}]}'%geom,
            'series': '%s'%series,
            'tipoBusqueda': 'VI'}
    return data
```

Based on the information above, if the requests are made one at a time, everything works fine:

```
>>> requests.post(url,data=payload(series[0],geom))
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.post(url,data=payload(series[1],geom))
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.post(url,data=payload(series[2],geom))
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.post(url,data=payload(series[3],geom))
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.post(url,data=payload(series[4],geom))
<Response [200]>
```

However, if I wrap those same requests in a loop then the error occurs, with all but the first 404 responses being:

```
>>> r = []
>>> for serie in series:
...     r.append(requests.post(url,data=payload(serie,geom)))
...
>>> r
[<Response [200]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [404]>]
```

I have spent a lot of time looking for solutions without success, some of them have been to use sessions passed in the headers `{'Connection':'Close'}`, others consisted of also passing in the headers `{'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 ( Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'}`. I've also tried adding delays between each request and using threads. None of this has worked

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the endpoint only accepts requests every 1 sec / 1min and so on etc. I know some APIs don't like to be hammered. Which a loop could do. Try adding `time.sleep(5)` before the loop starts again, this ...

```py
import requests
import time

r = []

for serie in series:
    r.append(requests.post(url, data=payload(serie,geom))
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds between requests
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however as I indicated in the question I already tried that solution, at least with lower times. Using delays greater than 7 seconds works most of the time, however I have to make many requests and cannot afford these delays.

Comment: ah ok i missed that bit. I don't think that would work then. I would possibly drop the API creator an email and see if they limit times on their requests.